# Unable to get options in select field from object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, actionview, form-helpers

can any one help me or give a link ,how to use select field where options are from object,what i tried is
     `<%= f.select "subject","id ", Hash[@subject_final.collect{|p| [p['name'],p['id']]}],{:prompt => 'Select Subject'} %>where subject=>is select field name`
  in my case i get an error
`ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method subject for #<Chapter:0xb6c36a5c>) @subject_final => [{"name"=>"11 A Bio groupMATHS", "id"=>9}, {"name"=>"9A 2011maths", "id"=>10}]`

I went through this one [form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)

Comment: If you're referencing `subject`, then that relationship needs to be defined on the model driving the form.

Comment: @tadman: I am not referencing subject should be <select name="subject"> this is what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the `subject` method on the `Chapter` model.

Also the hash you're building inline in the select can be tidied up with...

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@subject_final, :id, :name)
```

Comment: Previously i missed to add a belongs_to in my model,after adding that form is rendered but select field is empty